# libcpmt.lib cannot open file

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

Installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to get the Windows compiler and I have installed the Windows 8.1 sdk.

Trying to write fairly simple socket server program. I'm just using a text editor and the command line because my project is simple.

Includeing:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

code...
```

I'm compiling with `cl /EHsc srv.cpp` and I get an error `cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'`.

I have run vcvars32.bat and my LIB dir's are set correctly. However, I can't actually find `libcpmt.lib` on my system. Where would I get it? Do I even need it? How do I get around this?

I've read every related problem on SO and google and my problem is not a duplicate of any of them. It appears I do not have libcpmt.lib and I don't know where I would get it.

Comment: It needs to be present in the vc\lib subdirectory, along with libcmt.lib and msvcrt.lib and a bunch of others.  Use the IDE to compile "hello world" first.